# Obtaining value of Gridview Cell without having to use SelectedIndex etc

Tags: c#, gridview, compare, cell

I am currently trying to access a cell to obtain the value within it and compare it to todays date.

If the cells value is less than todays date I want to say a "Submission" is due if there has not already been one (if the cells value is the default empty Text then there is no submission).

Example Gridview:

ID     SubDate    Name     Recieved     File      Comments        // Column Headers
11111 | 2011/04 |    -    |    -     |    -     |    n/a           // Rows contents

Going by the example Gridview, I want to get the date in "SubDate" which is 2011/04. And compare it to todays date. Since it is less than todays date I want to replace the "-" in the other cells with "No Submission".

My attempts so far have not worked:

```
        DateTime today = System.DateTime.Now;
        string subdate;

            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(/* Need to Get Cell Value Here*/);
            subdate = date.ToShortDateString();

            if (date <= today)
            {                 
                if (GridView1.EmptyDataText == "-")
                {
                    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Submission";
                }
            }
```

Anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you realy have to break in to the GridView? Consider separating your data from the UI representaion. For example you can bind to a `List<Submitions>`  where

```
public class Submition
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string SubmitionName { get; set; }


    public string SubmitionNameView
    {
        get
        {
            if (date <= DateTime.Now && SubmitionName == "-")
                return "No Submission";
            else
                return SubmitionName;
        }
        set
        {
            SubmitionName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And bind your GridView columns to SubmitionNameView insted of SubmitionName;